# I am trying to install ionic and getting error coredova 404 not found

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Here is my command and error

**$ npm install -g cordova ionic**

Then I am getting this error

**npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: cordova@lat**est

**npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/satyen/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T14_55_56_732Z-debug.log**

I already installed node.js v9.1.0 and npm v5.5.1

Please help me out this.

Answer (score 1):

The package is called cordova, not cor**e**dova

Update your command to

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
```